# JSF - Command button action not working when it comes from an ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, managed-bean, commandbutton

I have two pages: login.xhtml (which has two forms, one to login in the application and another to register a new user) and user-registration.xhtml (which is called by the second form).

I am doing an ajax call as suggested here ([How can we use multiple <h:messages> tags or <h:message> tags in a single JSF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082911/how-can-we-use-multiple-hmessages-tags-or-hmessage-tags-in-a-single-jsf-pa)) in order to have multiple h:messages (one in each form). So I have the following:

```
<h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{loginController.register}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem is that in the user-registration page I have a form with:

```
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userRegistrationController.create}" />
```

And the method userRegistrationController.create is not being called. It happens the same as in [JSF Action Method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586489/jsf-action-method-not-being-called)

But I am using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2) and I cannot use the proposed solution as I have to put render="@form".

Any idea of how to solve this?

BalusC, I think it is not duplicate. If I delete

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
```

from the login.xhtml page then the command button in user-registration.xhtml page works perfectly. But i don't want to delete it.

Comment: BalusC, I think it is not duplicate. If i delete <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" /> from the login.xhtml page then the command button in user-registration.xhtml page works perfectly.

Comment: Problem suggests a JS error. You have nowhere excluded that from being the cause based on the duplicate.

Comment: BalusC, I didn't understand what you tried to tell me. My English is not very good.

Comment: Finally I fixed it putting in the login.xhtml page:

<h:body>
    <h:outputScript library="omnifaces" name="fixviewstate.js" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>

as you suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/hcommandbutton-hcommandlink-does-not-work-on-first-click-works-only-on-second